# I can't find the Create [Insert Shape Name] button in Blender 2.9

Tags: objects

So I'm trying to create a hexagon in blender by changing the amount of vertices to 6. I've looked at some Youtube tutorials and they all had a "Create circle" button and I can't find one on my end. I selected the circle and I can't find it.
[image: heres an image of the create circle button not being found]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you see it if you just created the circle in the lower left corner. If you did any action in between - it's gone.  Depending on the action you may be able to get it back by typing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The "button" is called the "Last Operator Adjust panel" in the blender literature. It is also sometimes called the "Redo" panel. It shows up in the lower left corner of the 3D Viewport whenever you execute an operation in Blender.  If you click on it, after adding a circle, it opens to this menu:

[image: Opened last operator adjust panel]

If you happen to click away from the object you've created; the button/panel will disappear.  *However* until you do something else you can get it back by typing <kbd>F9</kbd>  (That's the F9 function key.)